# Windows Mobile Application Donate Button

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm developing a mobile application where people could donate money to charity organisations. Ex: money donation for a hospital to buy medicine for the poor(just an example). I've been looking for a way to add a donate option but i couldn't find any.

Anyone know how to add a way to donate via Paypal or any other method.

Comment: Well, take a look at the PayPal API to find a way to incorporate it. The following site lists all the APIs available for PayPal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/

Comment: It doesn't have for windows mobile. only show for ios and android.

Comment: Well, there are REST APIs, which comes down to sending http requests. That's also possible from a windows mobile device.

Comment: i'll try that way. I didn't know what REST API's were before i'm a beginner. thank you.